# Changing Opacity with Mouse Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, opacity

I am trying to change the opacity of an element (in this instance a .png) based on mouse position.

I found this great example for color: http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/

```
var $win = $(window),
w = 0,h = 0,
rgb = [],
getWidth = function() {
    w = $win.width();
    h = $win.height();
};

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {

rgb = [
    Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
    Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
    150
];

$(document.body).css('background','rgb('+rgb.join(',')+')'); }).resize();
```

but I am confused how I might do it with opacity. 
I want the same smooth and seamless effect.

All help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly simple:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/161/)

```
$(function(){
    var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,h = 0,
    opacity = 1,
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };

    $win.mousemove(function(e) {
        getWidth();
        opacity = (e.pageX/w * 0.5) + (e.pageY/h * 0.5);

        $('#myElement').css('opacity',opacity);

    });
});
```

I edited out the whole resize thing because it didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper"><h1></h1></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WV8jX/159/

```
var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,
    h = 0,
    opacity = 0,
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {

    opacity = (e.pageX/w) * (e.pageY/h);
    $('h1').text(opacity);

    $('#wrapper').css('opacity',opacity);

}).resize();
```