# Change div opacity with mouse position

Tags: jquery, position, mouseevent, opacity

I am trying to make an element's opacity change depending on mouse position. I found this solution here – [Changing Opacity with Mouse Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853321/changing-opacity-with-mouse-position) – but I need one modification. I am looking for the opacity to be 0 in the vertical and horizontal **center** of the element. The further away from the center, the more the opacity.

Here's my dev page: http://www.bjornfloki.com/dev/spoon

I'm using the following script:

```
var $win = $(window),
w = 0,h = 0,
opacity = 1,
getWidth = function() {
    w = $win.width();
    h = $win.height();
};

$win.mousemove(function(e) {
    getWidth();
    opacity = (e.pageX/w * 0.5) + (e.pageY/h * 0.5);

    $('#myElement').css('opacity',opacity);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **[Plunker - Preview](http://embed.plnkr.co/cRN2pCA0rDb3Z2fIbLjW/preview)**

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/haxphbqn/)**

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
        var me = $("#scene"),
            cx = me.offset().left + me.width() / 2,
            cy = me.offset().top + me.height() / 2,
            d = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cx, 2) + Math.pow(cy, 2))),
            md = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e.pageX - cx, 2) + Math.pow(e.pageY - cy, 2)));
        me.css('opacity', md / d);
 -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="scene" class="scene" style="position: relative;">
    <li class="layer beresponsive" data-depth="0" style="position: relative; display: block; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
        <img src="http://www.bjornfloki.com/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master-child/images/bg-eyes.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="00" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
        <img id="gradient" src="http://www.bjornfloki.com/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master-child/images/empty.png" style="opacity: 0.196366554362154;" />
    </li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="00" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
        <img src="http://www.bjornfloki.com/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master-child/images/spoon-logo-1920.png" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Venkata, a wonderful solution, thank you so much! It works like it should except the opacity should be reversed – I'm looking for the opacity to be 0 in the center, 1 on the other edges. Right now it is 1 in the center, 0 in the outer edges: http://www.bjornfloki.com/dev/spoon (Note that the function is being applied to an empty PNG to produce the background effect, not the bg-eyes.jpg image)

Comment: Oops! Thats overlooked. I just updated by reversing and grab some html from your site and added it to fiddle and here, have a look.

Comment: You are amazing my friend! I used the code exactly as you provided but in the script I replaced #scene with #gradient to get the look exactly as I wanted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

set the centerX to be the position of horizontal center then centerY to be the vertical center.
Compute the opacity by combining the modulos of the currentX and currentY position to the centerX and centerY.

Like opacity = [1-(centerX % currentX)] + [1-(centerY % currentY)]

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help y

```
    var window_xy_addition = $(window).height() + $(window).width();
    var mouse_position_xy_addition = event.pageY + event.pageX;
    $("#change_opacity").css("opacity", (mouse_position_xy_addition/window_xy_addition));
```